# Controlling and selecting wifi from app in ios

Tags: ios, wifi, network-protocols

I would like to build an application that will control hardware system connected in wifi,for that i would like to know whether apple or any other provides any control in managing WiFi through app,it is a show stopper for this i have referred Stumbler in code google and Wifi master but they are missing in their associated frame works please  help me on this..

Comment: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: using reachebility you can check your WiFi connection.

Comment: Hi kirti, i am looking for library or class reference that can manage Wifi connection including their SSID,BSSID etc pls help me

Comment: Hi, @ArunChandran Are you done with this integration?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned jail-breaking, so I am assuming you not talking about using jailbroken devices or private frameworks - i.e. you want an app that can be approved for the App Store.

There are no generally accessible frameworks that you can use to control the device Wi Fi connection.

Apple does offer the Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC) feature as part of the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).  This feature makes it easy for a user to configure a new accessory to join an existing WiFi network by sharing wireless credentials.

Once your device or accessory is on the Wi Fi network then you can use standard TCP/IP communications which doesn't require any special interaction with the iOS device WiFi settings

Comment: Hi,Paul thanks but we have already designed H/W part for this and it is hard to register under MFi program,we have referred that,apple has any restriction on this.i think after 2010 no more libs are updated on this

Comment: Then you will need to provide instructions for the user on how to get the device onto the same wifi network